# Solicitud GET me devuelve null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de editar datos que tengo en una tabla de "Agentes" (User), y para eso estoy utilizando un modal para editarlos, y al momento de darle click al boton de editar, me lanza error en la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo el botón:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AgentesEdit" 
data-agenteid="@item.AgenteId" data-nombre="@item.Nombre" data-correo="@item.Correo" data-servicio="@item.ServicioNivel.Descripcion" data-telefonooficina="@item.TelefonoOficina" data-telefonomovil="@item.TelefonoMovil" data-rol="@item.Rol"
><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">Editar con modal</i></button>
```

Y para obtener los datos que quiero, tengo unas variables que por medio de data en el boton de editar, me los envía a través de jquery:

```
var AgenteId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('agenteid');

var URL = '@Url.Action("EditarAgente", "Agentes")' + '/' + AgenteId;
```

Donde paso el id del agente por la url del controlador que tengo para filtar el id de los agentes.

```
public JsonResult EditarAgente(int AgenteId)
{
     //ViewBag.ServicioNivelId = new SelectList(db.ServicioNiveles, "ServicioNivelId", "Descripcion");

     var Agente = db.Agentes.ToList().Find(x => x.AgenteId.Equals(AgenteId));

     return Json(Agente, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: 404 es que no encuentra esa ruta en el servidor. Seguro que la ruta del controlador es `/Agentes/EditarAgente/1017/1017`?

Comment: Según yo así debe de ser la URL que tengo en la variable `URL`, por que sí le quito la concatenación con la variable de AgenteId, no me devuelve 404 si no 500 de error...

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que:

- El controlador existe y se llama **Agentes**.
- En el `startup.cs` o en el `program.cs` tienes el routing por defecto.

El problema principal:

```
public JsonResult EditarAgente(int AgenteId)
```

Motivo:

- El enrutamiento no se cumple.

El problema secundario:

- Estás enviando mal la URL, tiene el mismo Id dos veces. Asegúrate que sea 1 solo, tal cual está especificado en el `action` de tu `controller`.

### Soluciones

- La primera opción:

Reemplazar

```
public JsonResult EditarAgente(int AgenteId)
```

Por:

```
public JsonResult EditarAgente(int id)
```

- La segunda opción:

Reemplazar:

```
public JsonResult EditarAgente(int AgenteId)
```

Por:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("EditarAgente/{AgenteId:int}")]
public JsonResult EditarAgente(int AgenteId)
```

Sugerencia:

En base a las preguntas que vas realizando en el sitio, te invito a ver este workshop de ASPnet MVC:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY&list=PL-_pdwtmHN2TcXVCoDc0qSqzwRFgJarO_&index=13

Aunque es de la versión 5 con full dotnet framework, los mismos conceptos se mantienen para nuevas versiones.

Saludos.